# Testnet validator never starts

Tags: validator

I'm trying to start a testnet validator, after a bunch of tests with/without snapshots, with/without genesis, with bunch of validators from docs and from rpc filter (always with api.testnet.solana.com) I can't get it working, after a few minutes the validator just close with "Unable to find any RPC"...

I tried with a clean ledger, with/without snapshots params (and processing). After snapshots *recovery* the monitor says "unknown health" always...
You can see all the params I'm using in the options.

Thanks in advance

```
[2024-02-08T12:54:52.792765310Z INFO  solana_validator] solana-validator 1.17.20 (src:09e0300b; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)
[2024-02-08T12:54:52.792803531Z INFO  solana_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-validator",
            "--gossip-port",
            "8000",
            "--dynamic-port-range",
            "8000-8022",
            "--identity",
            "/home/rotsen/tmp/jito-validator/identities/id.json",
            "--ledger",
            "/home/rotsen/tmp/jito-validator/ledger",
            "--expected-genesis-hash",
            "4uhcVJyU9pJkvQyS88uRDiswHXSCkY3zQawwpjk2NsNY",
            "--limit-ledger-size",
            "50000000",
            "--contact-debug-interval",
            "120000",
            "--log",
            "/home/rotsen/tmp/jito-validator/solana-validator.log",
            "--no-port-check",
            "--no-os-cpu-stats-reporting",
            "--no-os-memory-stats-reporting",
            "--no-os-network-limits-test",
            "--no-os-network-stats-reporting",
            "--private-rpc",
            "--rpc-bind-address",
            "127.0.0.1",
            "--rpc-port",
            "8899",
            "--full-rpc-api",
            "--rpc-threads",
            "4",
            "--skip-poh-verify",
            "--no-poh-speed-test",
            "--wal-recovery-mode",
            "skip_any_corrupted_record",
            "--rocksdb-shred-compaction",
            "fifo",
            "--accounts-db-skip-shrink",
            "--full-snapshot-interval-slots",
            "12000",
            "--maximum-incremental-snapshots-to-retain",
            "2",
            "--incremental-snapshots",
            "--vote-account",
            "/home/rotsen/tmp/jito-validator/identities/vote-account.json",
            "--rpc-pubsub-enable-vote-subscription",
            "--rpc-pubsub-notification-threads",
            "2",
            "--accounts-index-memory-limit-mb",
            "10000",
            "--replay-slots-concurrently",
            "--no-os-disk-stats-reporting",
            "--health-check-slot-distance",
            "300",
            "--known-validator",
... bunch of validators just to test 
            "zjG7sHeExhC7tfLZwTJwHH3zzDSqDcwRVe2LdXg389j",
            "--entrypoint",
            "entrypoint.testnet.solana.com:8001",
            "--entrypoint",
            "entrypoint2.testnet.solana.com:8001",
            "--entrypoint",
            "entrypoint3.testnet.solana.com:8001",
        ],
    }
[2024-02-08T12:54:52.793318977Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-02-08T12:54:52.793331247Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2024-02-08T12:54:52.793338337Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.292164702Z INFO  solana_validator] obtained shred-version 14676 from 35.203.170.30:8001
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.294875157Z INFO  solana_validator] Contacting 139.178.68.207:8001 to determine the validator's public IP address
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.296102313Z INFO  solana_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.677920484Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] host id: 1pDMJMkbH5HexixGiwJ1yMuH9EMz28DGyWebuRZy6qA
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.678259318Z INFO  solana_entry::entry] Loading "libpoh-simd.so"
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.678595073Z INFO  solana_perf::perf_libs] perf-libs found at "/home/rotsen/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.17.20/solana-release/bin/perf-libs"
[2024-02-08T12:54:53.678798845Z INFO  solana_perf::perf_libs] setting ld_library_path to: "/home/rotsen/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.17.20/solana-release/bin/perf-libs:/nix/store/hs1zphws1iyddrvfyqs7qj9qw6qqs0mc-icu4c-68.2/lib"

[2024-02-08T13:00:20.223726157Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that tcp ports [(8000, TcpListener { addr: 0.0.0.0:8000, fd: 83 })] are reachable from 139.178.68.207:8001
[2024-02-08T13:00:20.788610515Z INFO  solana_net_utils] tcp/8000 is reachable
[2024-02-08T13:00:20.788784958Z INFO  solana_net_utils] Checking that udp ports [8000, 8001, 8003, 8004, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 8009, 8010, 8012] are reachable from 139.178.68.207:8001
[2024-02-08T13:00:21.428413455Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8000, 8001, 8003, 8004], reachable udp ports: {8003, 8004, 8000, 8001}
[2024-02-08T13:00:22.068134772Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8005, 8006, 8007, 8008], reachable udp ports: {8006, 8007, 8005, 8008}
[2024-02-08T13:00:22.708032990Z INFO  solana_net_utils] checked udp ports: [8009, 8010, 8012], reachable udp ports: {8010, 8009, 8012}
[2024-02-08T12:54:54.690228554Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap]
    RPC Address       |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version | RPC  |PubSub|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------
    RPC Enabled Nodes: 0
[2024-02-08T12:54:54.690271065Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Searching for an RPC service with shred version 14676...
[2024-02-08T12:54:54.690277065Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Total 0 RPC nodes found. 0 known, 0 blacklisted
[2024-02-08T12:54:55.690367916Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap]
    RPC Address       |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version | RPC  |PubSub|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------
    RPC Enabled Nodes: 0
...............................
[2024-02-08T12:55:03.691499188Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Searching for an RPC service with shred version 14676 (Retrying: Wait for known rpc peers)...
[2024-02-08T12:55:03.691505068Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Total 0 RPC nodes found. 0 known, 0 blacklisted
[2024-02-08T12:55:03.697416435Z INFO  solana_gossip::cluster_info]
    IP Address        |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version |Gossip|TPUvote| TPU  |TPUfwd| TVU  |TVU Q |ServeR|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+---------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+--------
    191.81.204.121  me|  2401 | 1pDMJMkbH5HexixGiwJ1yMuH9EMz28DGyWebuRZy6qA | 1.17.20 | 8000 |  none | none | none | none | none | none | 14676
    Nodes: 0
    Spies: 1

    RPC Address       |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version | RPC  |PubSub|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------
    RPC Enabled Nodes: 0
[2024-02-08T12:55:04.691592799Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap]
    RPC Address       |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version | RPC  |PubSub|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------
    RPC Enabled Nodes: 0
```